# How to get 2 sums in single query in sql laravel

Tags: laravel, database

I want to achieve  2 results  (aggregate functions) in single query in laravel.

```
$user=Auth::guard('api')->user(); 
$data['current_month_score']= UserScore::whereMonth('created_at',now()->month)->where('user_id',$user->id)->sum('score');
$data['current_month_score']= UserScore::where('user_id',$user->id)->sum('score');
```

this gives me correct result but i want to achieve this in 1 query.

Is this possible if so, how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$user = Auth::guard('api')->user(); 
$data = UserScore::selectRaw('SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(created_at) = ? THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS current_month_score, SUM(score) AS total_score', [now()->month])
                 ->where('user_id', $user->id)
                 ->first();
```

The `$data` variable will contain an object with two properties: `current_month_score` and `total_score`. You can access these values using $data->current_month_score and $data->total_score.